# A non-serializable value was detected in the state

Tags: javascript, jquery, redux, react-redux

I randomly get the  `non-serializable` error in my react-native app.
I already searched a lot about it before posting the question, and I understand that it should not contain the `non-serializable` values. but in my app, I already double checked before posting the question that it should not contain.

Here is the function that I am invoking, but only some times it throws the error, not all time

```
const onSendRequest = (recievedUser) => {
    console.log('user received in ActivityScreen: ', recievedUser.firstName);
    if (!recievedUser) {
      return;
    }
    if (sentto.filter((user) => user.email === recievedUser.email)[0]) {
      console.log("already sent to this user");
      return;
    }
    setSentto((previousState) => {
      return [...previousState, recievedUser];
    });
    store.dispatch(
      sentRequestsActions.setList([...alreadySentTo, recievedUser])
    );
    FriendService.sendRequest(loggedInUser.id, recievedUser.id).then((resp) => {
      console.log("Sent");
    });
  };
```

`store.js`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import likeReducer from "./like";
import sentRequests from "./sentRequests";
import loggedInUserSlice from "./loggedInUser";
import commentsReducer from "./comments";

console.log("store inited");

export default store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    like: likeReducer,
    comments: commentsReducer,
    loggedInUserSlice: loggedInUserSlice.reducer,
    sentRequests,
  },
});
```

`sentRequest.js`

```
import { createSlice } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";

let initialState = [];

const sentRequestSlice = createSlice({
  name: "sentRequestSlice",
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    setList: (state, newState) => {
      // newState.payload.forEach((user) => {
      //   console.log("Sent to: ", user.firstName);
      // });
      return (state = newState.payload);
    },
    removeFriend: () => {
      console.log("friend removed");
    },
    getList: (state) => {
      return state.payload;
    },
  },
});

export const sentRequestsActions = sentRequestSlice.actions;

export default sentRequestSlice.reducer;
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Comment: The error message should also give you more info, like the explicit path it was found at. Would help sharing that here. Also, what exactly is `recievedUser`?

Comment: yes it says in `in the path: `sentRequests.1``
I already read that path, but still not able to figure out, what is triggering the issue
`recievedUser` is an object

Comment: So it is caused by either the `setList` or the `getList` action. My personal assumption would be that `recievedUser` is not a *plain* object, but some kind of class instance.

Comment: Thank you so much @phry, you were right, it was caused by `setList` and the problem was due to some problem, sometimes recievedUser would get Class instead of plain object what was causing the issue randomly.